# docker-compose with a war via volume fails on digital ocean debian but not other debian distros (my home box, work box as well)

Tags: docker, war, docker-compose

on digitalocean:

if i use docker compose with a tomcat container that has the war i am trying to use already in webapps via the tomcat container, compose works...

Dockerfile for Tomcat container with built in war (works):

```
FROM clegge/java7
MAINTAINER christopher.j.legge@gmail.com

RUN wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.65/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.65.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf apache-tomcat-7.0.65.tar.gz
RUN mv apache-tomcat-7.0.65 /opt/tomcat7
RUN rm apache-tomcat-7.0.65.tar.gz

RUN echo "export CATALINA_HOME=\"/opt/tomcat7\"" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN sed -i '/<\/tomcat-users>/ i\<user username="test" password="test~" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-status"/>' /opt/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml

VOLUME /opt/tomcat7/webapps
ADD app.war /opt/tomcat7/webapps/app.war
EXPOSE 8080

CMD /opt/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh && tail -f /opt/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
```

if i use that container with docker compose, everything works great!

if i try to push the war file in via my docker-compose yml the contianer goes up and never inflates the war...

```
tomcat:
  image: tomcat:8.0
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - base-0.2.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/base.war
  links:
    - postgres

postgres:
  image: clegge/postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
   - DB_USER_NAME=test_crud
   - DB_PASSWORD=test_crud
   - DB_NAME=base_db
```

no error in the logs...

this also fails on my godaddy box...  I have tried every flavor of linux on digital ocean... nothing works...  i think it is a problem because the digital ocean instance is a container itself...  any thoughts?

Comment: MAybe godaddy has other restrictions, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33693934/6309?

Comment: @VonC Maybe, bothers me with digital ocean... They literally sell droplets advertised as docker specific yet would not offer any support